# Js, document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML, error

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm new to javascript, and I'm try to write out some code for a test site and I'm having some problems, dow below is my code and I keep getting this error and i can't figure out why.

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("h3").innerHTML = "<h3>You Are up to date!</h3>"')`

This is my second method i tried using. what I'm trying to do it have a  have a version list this first one i had was that it would pull a .js file and build a table, but that didn't work so i thought i would try this, but guess what happened? not working

my code that I'm using now is below. if you can help that would be amazing. 
thanks, Dakmessier

```
var current = "1.0";
function get_latest(){
document.getElementById("bob").innerHTML = current;
}

if (local != current){
document.getElementById("Get").innerHTML = "<button><a href=\"bla\">Get the Latest Update!</a></button>";
} else if (local == current){
 document.getElementById("h3").innerHTML = "<h3>You Are up to date!</h3>";
} else {
document.getElementById("h3").innerHTML = "<h3>Sorry, unable to check for update.</h3>";
}
```

Comment: There is no element with the ID `h3`, that's a tagname

Comment: well i added a id that was h3, but i have been working with my code and have removed that id and I'm updating the code above now

Comment: You've shown your JavaScript, could you show the relevant HTML upon which the JavaScript is expected to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById(id)` finds an element with a given id value in your HTML.  An id value looks like this:

```
<div id="myHeader">Some Content</div>
```

And, then you can find that element with:

```
document.getElementById("myHeader");
```

ID values must be unique in each document so there should only ever be one element with a given ID.

---

If an id isn't what you really want, you can find elements other ways, by tag type, by class name, by attribute, etc... using CSS selectors with `document.querySelectorAll()`.

For example, if you wanted to find all `<h3>` tags, you could do this:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("h3");
```

---

Here are some other reasons that `document.getElementById(...)` might fail to find what you want it to find:

1. The Javascript code is running before the DOM elements have been parsed and loaded so thus the element is actually not there yet when you're running the code.  This is common with code run from the `<head>` section of the document.
2. You have an HTML error in how you are specifying the id value in the HTML.
3. You have an HTML error that causes the browser not to parse your HTML properly.
4. You have a script error that cause your script to abort before it gets to the part you want to run.

Comment: yep i understand that, thats i what i have going but I'm still getting that error

Comment: @Dakmessier - You will need to show us your HTML (ideally show us the whole document).  Another reason that it may not find the desired item is if you are running your Javascript BEFORE the DOM has been loaded (like if the code is running in the `<head>` section of the document).

Comment: so if i change where the `<script>` page is run from so instead of the head tag, to a footer tag that i may fix it?

Comment: @Dakmessier - You can try moving the `<script>` tag to right before `</body>` to see if that fixes it.  Whether that is the issue or not depends upon several things that you have not shown us so I don't know if that is actually the issue or not.  You can read the first part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `document.getElementById` returns null if it can't find an element with the Id specified.

Also the statement:

```
if (local != current){
 // ..
} else if (local == current){
 // ..
} else {
 // ..
}
```

is a bit odd. If `local != current` is `false` then `local == current` must be `true`. The `else if (...)` is redundant and the `else` part will never be run.

Comment: well i just going to let people download the site to use, so then the .js file is hosted else where and this is the local. file so if it can't find the current var then is will go to the else and say it can't find it

Comment: The `else` part can't be reached, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

hey man the bast thing you should do is the following example, feel free to copy it on your snippet of code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I WILL EXPLAIN YOU THIS ANSWER: this is an html + an inline script that makes the inner html work. As far as concerned with your answer it was unclear where your code stopped, anyway test my snippet of code and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I was having the same issue and was trying hard to find the solution for some time.

The problem was that I was executing the script before the page loaded. Thus it wasn't able to find the object that we're trying to catch.

So either use jquery document.ready function or else move your script to the end of the html.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

fix an error of getting the value of a as null

```
Uncaught TypeError: a is null
```

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <script>
        let a = document.getElementById('i');
        document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
            a.innerHTML='clean';
        })
        
    </script>
<body>
    <h3 id="i">not clean</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

this shows as error in console as

```
Uncaught TypeError: a is null
```

you can fix it by making your script tag before

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="i">not clean</h3>
    <script>
        let a = document.getElementById('i');
        document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
            a.innerHTML='clean';
        })
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this might fix!!